# ColorGame with Java (like Minesweeper)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, flood-fill

so my task is to create a game with gui in java. Game is described like this:

The game takes place in the field of size n × m, where m and n are less than 50.
Each cell contains a single color or character or number (your choice) from a set of
possible values. The program is defined by three parameters n, m, k. The program
randomly places characters / colors / numbers on a two-dimensional field. The first
color / character / number belongs to the player. The object of the game is to have
the player paint the entire playing field with their color. Coloring is enabled by
selecting the source field and the target field.
The game replaces all adjacent fields with the target color if they are the same color
as the target field in the source field color.
The game shows the user a list of colors / characters / numbers.
When the user paints the entire field, the game ends and the number of moves is
number of selected fields.

I've created the gui:

public GGGame {

```
    Butt0nz();
    theFrame();


}
public void Butt0nz() {


    colors.add(Color.RED);
    colors.add(Color.GREEN);
    colors.add(Color.BLUE);
    colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
    colors.add(Color.ORANGE);


     b1 = new JButton("Restart");
     b1.addActionListener(this);
     b2 = new JButton("Moves: "+ "0");
     b3 = new JButton("Is continuation possible: ");


     menubar = new JMenuBar();
     file = new JMenu("File");
     open = new JMenuItem("Open");
     save = new JMenuItem("Save");
     close = new JMenuItem("Exit");


     save.addActionListener(this);
     open.addActionListener(this);
     close.addActionListener(this);

     menubar.add(file);
     file.add(open);
     file.add(save);
     file.add(close);




}

public Color randomColor() {

    return colors.get(new Random().nextInt(colors.size()));
}


public void theFrame() {


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(n, m));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
        {

            button[i][j] = new JButton();
            button[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            button[i][j].setBackground(randomColor());
            panel.add(button[i][j]);
        }
    }


    JPanel butt0n = new JPanel();
    butt0n.add(b1);
    butt0n.add(b2);
    butt0n.add(b3);

    setJMenuBar(menubar);
    setTitle("Color Game");
    add(butt0n, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

'''

I just want some recommendations on how to start about the logic of the game. I read some stuff and I understand that the logic of the game is like minesweeper's and I know that FloodFill Algorithm should be implemented for it to work but I just want more clear answers on how I should start.

Comment: *The program is defined by three parameters n, m, k*... What does 'k' do?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you started nicely with `JButton`s in a `GridLayout(n, m)`, because that will let you handle the events more cleanly than adding a mouse listener to a big panel with custom paintings.

I would suggest putting the grid (ie the `JPanel` with the `GridLayout` of `JButton`s) into a `JScrollPane` so as to have bigger buttons. For example if no `JScrollPane` is used, and the program is intended to run in a screen with resolution for example 1366x768 and you use up to 1200x700 pixels (to leave some to spare for the window borders themselves), in a 50x50 game that would mean 24x14 (width times height) pixels per button. If that's ok with you, it might not be good to rely on the resolution of the screen. Instead put the grid inside a `JScrollPane`. I'm not suggesting though buttons like 300x300 obviously (because that would be unnecessarily large), but maybe 30x30 for example, or something even bigger, that would not be too hard to click.

Another idea is to let the user set the size of each button on-the-fly, ie via a setting in the program, for example it could be two sliders (one for width and one for height).

I would suggest not going about the *numbers* nor the *characters* option, because that would be harder to notice than setting the background color.

I would suggest a *not*-intense color for the background of each button, for obvious reasons. For example consider filling the entire area with the colors you specified... That could possibly blind someone (myself at least haha). For example you may use the [`darker()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#darker--) versions of those colors. If that doesn't work, I tested another option: adding some transparency (ie alpha color component) so as to let the original colors of the button to show through which are, as far as I know, designed not to blind people.

This is an example code of painting some buttons with transparent red color:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int rows = 10, cols = 10;

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, cols));

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                final JButton button = new JButton() {
                    @Override
                    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
                        super.paintComponent(g);
                        g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 50));
                        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                    }
                };
                button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
                panel.add(button);
            }

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("ColorGame.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And the result is in my opinion not going to blind anyone (although it is almost-clearly red):

[image: Sample run of demo grid]

The [Flood Fill algorithm in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#The_algorithm) is pretty well explained I think. So you shouldn't need something more to implement it other than that material there. It also provides some recursive pseudocodes to solve the problem.

To easily check for ending condition, you may use a counter/`int` of the number of buttons with the background equal to the player's picked color. When that number reaches equal to N times M then you end the game. But then don't forget to update your counter for each update of a button's background. If you don't want to use this counter, because for example it could make the code less clean and more error prone, then the simplest thing you can do is probably to iterate over every button after each move and count which buttons have the user's color as background, but that would be inefficient, although, efficiency for a problem of size at most 50x50 (ie 2500 color equality checks) is not a great deal in my opinion for this specific scenario.

For easier adjustments, I would suggest subclassing for example the `JButton` class, and override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return a shared object of type `Dimension` that will contain the values selected by the settings' sliders from the user. Then each time you update this shared mutable object, you will just call `revalidate()` on the `JScrollPane`'s `Viewport`'s view (ie the panel containing the buttons) and it will update the `JScrollPane`.

Since you subclassed `JButton` you may want to add the number of row and column which the button corresponds to in the grid, so when the `ActionListener` is invoked you will know where the user clicked (and just use the same `ActionListener` object for all sources/buttons). In that case you will probably need not forget to check for the `ActionEvent`'s *source* property (which is a button with row and column id) rather than any other button.

Even more appropriate than `JButton`s I think could be to use `JToggleButton`s. So in this way, you can let the user know which was the first button they selected of the pair of source-target buttons, and undo their initial selection if they click again the same button. Of course, when selecting a toggle button, you will need to maintain a reference to the first toggle button so as to match it with the second one and to know where to start.

That's all I have until now, to get you only started. If you need more information or clarifications then let me know in the comments.